# Is there a defined answer to whether hiding an H1 tag will get a site banned by Google?

Tags: seo, accessibility

I have been researching this for a few hours and I feel that I can't decide on what is right or wrong. This was asked before on Stackoverflow, but a couple of years ago so I thought I could ask again. I want to include H1 tags on my pages but hide them, because I have graphic in my banner, but I was taught to use an H1 tag for accessibility reasons.

I discovered that this can be considered SEO spamming and can get a site blacklisted, I do not want this. It was also discovered that using H1 tags can greatly increase the sites SEO when using relative headers.

So I want to use them and hide them, for two reasons, but avoid Google blacklisting my site, is there a standard accepted method to doing this, or will I need to choose between risking blacklisting and helping those with visual disabilities a better user experience?

Thanks in advance for any advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest method is just to include the image with an `alt` attribute in the `h1`:

```
<h1><img src="banner.png" alt="my banner text" /></h1>
```

And you can be assured that you won't be penalized for that. I have not seen any definitive information that doing image replacement will result in a higher ranking than using `alt` properly. Like most SEO lore, there is very little data. That said, as long as you are not trying to game the search engines and present something different to the user and the search engine, it's unlikely you'll be penalized for using image replacement.

If you do do image replacement, be sure to position the text off-screen by using absolute positioning or negative margins rather than `display: none` or `visibility: hidden` so that screen reader users can access the content.

Comment: For some back history, you can check out this blog post by Googler Maile Oyhe describing the SEO issues: http://maileohye.com/html-text-indent-not-messing-up-your-rankings/ ... and she links over to this post describing what steveax has as the solution: http://luigimontanez.com/2010/stop-using-text-indent-css-trick/

Comment: Excellent advice, thank you. All I wanted to do was to use an H1 tag to increase my SEO, as well as my sites accessibility, but as I had no need to display the H1 tag, I wanted to hide it. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You're not improving accessibility if you hide headings.

If you do so with `display: none;` or `visibility:hidden;`, it's as if you never added them in the first place: they won't be read by screen readers and obviously won't be displayed if CSS are enabled.
If you do so with negative `text-indent` or `left` absolute positioning, only blind people will read them but not partially-sighted people that don't use any screen reader, and they're way more than blind people (perhaps 10 times).